# Eigenvalue Function of Laplace Equation discretizes by nine-point stencil

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I'm trying to plot the eigenvalue function of the Laplace equation
$$-u_{xx}-u_{yy}=0,\;(x,y)\in (0,1)^2$$ with $$u(x,y)=0$$ on the boundary of the unit square. I have the nine-point stencil $$A=-\frac{1}{3}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -8 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right].$$
The equations for the inner points can be written as $Tu=0$. But when I tried to implement the matrix $T$ in Matlab and get the eigenvectors via the eig-function, it doesn't seem to be the right solution. My code for $T$ is 
(n is the number of inner points)
M=-8*eye(n)+diag(ones(n-1,1),1)+diag(ones(n-1,1),-1);
M2=diag(ones(n-1,1),1)+diag(ones(n-1,1),-1);
M3=eye(n)+diag(ones(n-1,1),1)+diag(ones(n-1,1),-1);
T=-1/3*(kron(eye(n),M)+kron(M2,M3));

I computed the smallest eigenvalue and eigenvector for n=63, but it's the reflected of what it should be (or at least exactly the opposite of the picture I have from a solution for the Laplace equation). 
[image]

So I think somewhere I forgot a -1, but I'm not sure where exactly. I already tried to add one in $T$, but that was not the right thing. Could you please help me?

best regards
Aione

Comment: What exactly is reflected? Are you troubled that the eigenvector has negative entries? Because the eigenvector is only determined up to a scalar factor. Or is there a problem with the eigenvalues?

Comment: No, my prolem is just, that it shows the negative entries. If I know, that the computed eigenvector should be multiplied by -1, does that hold for all of them?

Comment: Not always, it depends on the internals of the routine. You can multiply by the sign of the eigenvector to make it positive though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always thought I did something wrong, but it comes from the Matlab routine. I plotted some more eigenvectors and saw, that some of them have the right entries, but are rotated by 90 degree. Does that come from the routine, too? I never had to compute the eigenvectors for PDEs, so I'm not sure if they are still correct then.

Comment: What do you mean by rotated? That sounds like it is probably your error.

Comment: Well, the second smallest and third smallest eigenvectors have the same eigenvalues. My computed ones are <img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/9se51u.jpg" > and <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/6jowuf.png" > but should be <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/28kths.jpg" > and <img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/29dbpeq.jpg" >

Comment: Oh, if the eigenvalues are the same then you have a eigenspace of dimension higher than 1, and can have any number of different choices of basis for the eigenspace. MATLAB probably chooses them to be orthogonal, but even then there are options.